# Can't recover ext4 partition with TestDisk

Tags: linux, partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk

I have a disk with some primary NTFS partitions and a extended partition containing Linux and Swap partitions. I lost one of the logical Linux ones

I booted a live Linux CD (RipLinux) and TestDisk is able to recognize the lost partition (using Deeper Search, not Quick Search). It shows the Start and End positions in Cylinder-Head-Sector notation. If I press 'p' it shows the files inside it. Everything looks fine but some problems arise:

- I restored the partition but the Linux installation doesn't boot, and the live Linux CD can't mount it either, so I suppose that TestDisk didn't create the partition with the right Start/End positions
- I thought of noting down the Start and End positions and recreate that partition with Linux fdisk, but fdisk uses Sector notation instead of CHS notation. fdisk has an option to use CHS but it shows only the Cylinder and not Cylinder-Head-Sector, so I can't recreate the partition with the exact Start and End positions. Is there a way to translate CHS positions into Sector positions to feed them to fdisk?
- Each time I try things in TestDisk it has to scan the entire disk, is there a way to save the previous session or to tell TestDisk's Deeper Search to search only a specific part of the disk?

**EDIT**: added output of `tune2fs -l /dev/sda7` , it looks just the same as another Linux partition that works fine (except this one has the `needs_recovery` flag). I tried to use `fsck` but it gave lots of errors and failed to recover it

```
# tune2fs -l /dev/sda7
tune2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          b9164fa7-f5ac-43cc-9397-573482f5ab3a
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              701760
Block count:              2807040
Reserved block count:     140352
Free blocks:              1703406
Free inodes:              540871
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      685
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8160
Inode blocks per group:   510
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Tue Dec 16 23:30:48 2014
Last mount time:          Mon Dec 29 12:33:45 2014
Last write time:          Mon Dec 29 12:33:45 2014
Mount count:              6
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Tue Dec 16 23:30:48 2014
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          4248 MB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      6894974e-3ffa-4e83-bd2e-fecf440fb13f
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

Comment: It may help if You provide more info how did You lost it? If You have something valuable in this partition, I would suggest not writing to it (not to corrupt structure even more). What Linux and LiveCD are You using?

Comment: I used RipLinux as rescue system; the reason for the partition loss is unclear: I just tried to create a logical partition from Windows XP Disk Manager, it failed to create it and one of the existing logical partitions was gone after that

Comment: What does `tune2fs -l /dev/sdXN` show for this partition (boot from LiveCD, replace sdXN with correct device)? What does `parted -l` show?